# Where did my context menus go?

Tags: 11.10, unity, updates, menu

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and just did a software update (not sure what got updated) and now my context menus are gone.  When I right click on things I see nothing, but can still click around in the dark and make things in the now invisible menu happen (copy, paste, etc).  The same is true for the calendar (when I click the clock) or application menus (file, edit, etc).  Even extensions in Chrome are no longer dropping down.

Help!

Comment: Does this happen with other themes?.

Comment: not sure.  they came back for the moment.  it seems that if I close all open windows they'll start working and then after while they cut out again.  I'll test a different theme next time they're not working.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).